# What is UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _smoothscroll: responsible for?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, instruments

While profiling an app, realise that quite a lot of time (37%) is spent on the

```
UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _smoothscroll:
```

Have the impression that is related to the rendering of a view and its hierarchy but haven't been able to find any evidence to back this up.

Comment: If it starts with underscores, it's most likely private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a private method.
It's for slowing down during the deceleration.

You have probably special "drawRect" subview on your UITableViewCell.
Do check your subview of your UITableViewCell and see where you lose the performance.

Comment: thanks Jonas. Is there anything else that might affect that? Doesn't look like "drawRect" is overwritten. That's on a 3rd gen iPod touch on iOS 4.1. Does the overhead sound reasonable?

Comment: Is your scrolling smooth? or do you have problem there? 37% can be good, ... a % value is always related to the other performance impact. So if it's smooth, 37% can be a reasonable value.